# How to have a Django REST call kick off a job?

Tags: python, django

Sorry if this has been asked a bazillion times, but I am trying to accomplish something with Django but am not sure how to get started or what to search for for help.

What I would like to do is have Django web app spawn a (potentially long) task in response to a user hitting it with a REST web request.

- User goes to myserver.com/some/rest/call
- Django app routes that to a view which kicks off my job. Something as simple as subprocess is what I'm looking to do.
- Django view returns success to user immediately, i.e. does not wait for the long job to finish before returning a response.

Is a scenario like this possible?  It's unclear to me how the new job can be managed if the function that ultimately spwans it is going to return right away.

Thanks for any pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, this is a common pattern.  Most people use [celery](http://www.celeryproject.org) as the asynchronous task queue.  You could just use `subprocess` I suppose too.

In terms of tracking results of the job, that's up to you.  Celery certainly makes it easier to manage and track tasks as they're processed, but almost all systems need some type of datastore to capture the results from the operation.